# What to return in C when need to throw an exception in other language such as C++?

Tags: c, exception

I implemented a htoi(hex integer to octal integer) function in C.
The function signature is as following:

```
int htoi(char* s);
```

The basic logic is fairly simple and my main concern is how to deal with the extreme test data such as invalid hex number such as **oxazzz**, **ox???DFSLA**. Obviously, some magic number would not work, since the result could be any integers.

One solution I would like to take is change the function signature such as:

`int htoi(char* s, bool* error);`

And set error as true when s is not a valid hex number.But it seems that it is not a nice solution. Therefore, what should be the best practice to handle this situation since no exception throw mechanism available in C?

Comment: Isn't the convention something like this: `int void(char* s, int* result);` with the return value representing any errors.

Comment: first of all you should do `int void(char* s, bool *error);` if you want to return value from your function.

Comment: `void` is not a valid function name. You must have meant `htoi`.

Comment: For unrelated reasons, you should take `const char *s` rather than just `char *s`. You don't need to modify the data pointed to by `s`, and adding `const` says so.

Comment: Since you are returning `int` why do you say "octal integer"?

Comment: @larsmans oh yeah.... I meant `htoi` :)
@xiao you are welcome

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at how [`strtol(3`)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strtol.3.html) does it. Not saying it's ideal, just an example.

Comment: +1 In fact, instead of wasting time writing your own function, *use* `strtol()`.  It's C90 standard according to my man page.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to pass output variable in the function signature and return values as SUCESS/FAILURE

```
error_type function_name ( input_variable, *input_output_variable);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int htoi(char* s, int* result);
```

return 0 (or -1, or whatever you want) on failure.

Another option is:

```
int* htoi(char* s, int* result);
```

You return the pointer to `result` (the same pointer you passed in) if successful, `NULL` on failure.

I tend to like the latter style; `if (htoi(myString, &myInt) == NULL) { /* bad thing */ }`

Answer (score 2):

I would say you should document the fact that calling the function with an invalid string results in undefined behaviour. You can then return whatever number you like. I would also implement an IsHexNumber function  that tests for  a valid number. You thus give the users of your function a means by which they can write code that never passes a bad string, and you offload the error handling to a higher part of the code, which is where it belongs.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of using an extra argument is quite common. Use a pointer for the `error` argument, though. An even better idea is to return success/failure and store the actual result through a pointer.

Also, some C standard library functions (the `strtol` family) handle this by specifying that a function sets `errno` on error. This is another possibility, although it leads to the somewhat cumbersome idiom

```
errno = 0;  // errno may have been set previously
x = strtol(str, NULL, 10);
if (errno)
    // handle error
```

Comment: And the even more cumbersome idiom `int olderrno = errno; errno = 0; x = strtol(str, NULL, 10); int newerrno = errno; errno = olderrno; if (newerrno) ...` if your code is supposed to be library-safe, i.e. doesn't modify errno unless it needs to.

Comment: I do not like this design favor since it is relied on a global variable.

Comment: @xiao: `errno` is not necessarily a global variable. According to the C standard, it's an expression (macro, probably) that may expand to thread-local storage.

Answer (score 0):

Returning an error code seems to be the *de facto* standard, but in my opinion it's quite tedious and error prone.

Instead, you could use some exception handling system in C to actually `throw` an exception.

For example, I'm developing [exceptions4c](http://code.google.com/p/exceptions4c/), and there are many other [alternative libraries](http://code.google.com/p/exceptions4c/wiki/alternatives).